# Как узнать, что юзер уже использовал Free Trial

Tags: android, android-billing

Есть ли какой-либо способ узнать, что юзер уже участвовал во Free Trial подписки для данного Android приложения? C помощью Billing Library или каких-либо других средств?

Comment: стандартный подход - хранить у себя на серверах эти данные(дата активации, длительность, идентификатор устройства,....) и перед активацией "триала" делать запрос на свои сервера для проверки.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков так ведь эта информация связана не с аккаунтом приложения, а с аккаунтом пользователя в Google Play. Пользователь может создать новый аккаунт в приложении, но если он уже участвовал во Free Trial раньше, он увидит сообщение в окошке от Google "You've already participated in the free trial". Также он может сменить google-аккаунт в Google Play в любое время. Поэтому хранить на сервере такие данные никак не поможет.

Comment: вариант дать почитать скажем одну и туже книгу бесплатно как пробную подписку не подойдет?

Comment: кто вам мешает простите хранить уникальный идентификатор аккаунта(устройства\иного параметра к которому вы хотите привязать получение триала) у себя на серверах и использовать при попытках активации "триала"?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков это может сработать для новых подписчиков, но для пользователей, которые раньше воспользовались Free Trial, это ведь не сработает

Comment: У вас на данный момент есть способ узнать активировал ли пользователь триал или нет? если такой информацией вы не обладаете, как вы хотите ограничить старых пользователей уже использовавших функционал?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков для новых пользователей - да, мы можем узнать, активировал ли пользователь триал или нет. Но было много пользователей до текущего момента, для которых эту информации мы уже не можем получить

Comment: Для тех кого можете получить - сохраните у себя в базу(см комментарий №1), остальным придется подарить повторный триал т.к. вы не знаете доподлинно использовали они или нет :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков подарить повторный триал никак не получится, потому что это регулируется Google, а не приложением) Извиняюсь, но Вы, похоже, не очень знакомы с этой темой)